# How to make small polygons from shapefile and extract coordinates

Tags: r, leaflet, maps, tmap, mapview

I have a small shapefile here: https://login.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c6d62865c626fb4a2ab called bay.RDS

```
 library(tmap)
 library(leaflet)
 library(mapview)
 bay <- readRDS('bay.RDS')
 mapview(bay)
```

I am trying to draw 50 meter wide polygons from shore to shore right at the below point and extract coordinates from it.
I need multiple polygons next to each other but independently drawn as I need to color code them based on a column of values

```
pt <- st_sfc(st_point(c(-122.91, 38.17)), crs=4326)
mapview(bay) + mapview(pt, color ='red')
```

I have included a snapshot below of what I am trying to accomplish. I would appreciate it if someone can show me how I can
make just a couple of polygons and extract the coordinates from it so I can merge them to my dataset. Let me know if is not clear

[image]

Comment: The coordinates you need to extract, are those the intersection of lake transsects with the coastline (4 points per polygon) or the coastline sections per polygon (two polylines per polygon)?

Comment: The coordinates I need to extract are the 4 corners of each polygon @I_O

Comment: How do I keep the strings from shore to shore and avoid being extended to land?

Comment: Those are the intersection points, already addressed in update edit below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, using {sf} and {dplyr}:

**edit** this solution was substantially rewritten following the helpful comments by @Chris and @Salvador.

TLDR: below solution creates a horizontal baseline, buffers this baseline to result in a horizontal strip of chosen width, creates adjacent clones of this strip, combines them into a multipolygon, and rotates and shifts the mulitpolygon to expand southwards from a chosen anchor.

1. helper function `get_strips(...)` to return a multipolygon of adjacent strips:

```
get_strips <- function(n = 10, ## number of adjacent strips
                       strip_width = 1e3, # unit: m
                       strip_length = 1e5,
                       crs = 3857 ## default: 'google' mercator
                       ){
  ## make horizontal line of length 'strip_length':
  baseline <- matrix(c(-strip_length/2, strip_length/2, 0, 0), ncol = 2) |>
    st_linestring()
  ## make line a polygon of width 'strip_width'
  basestrip  <- baseline |> 
    st_buffer(strip_width/2, endCapStyle = 'FLAT')
  ## return a spatial dataframe of n adjacent strips from north to south:
  st_sf(strip_id = sprintf('strip_%02.f', 1:n),
        geometry = Map(1:n,
                       f = \(index) basestrip - c(0, index * strip_width - strip_width/2)
                       )|>
          st_sfc() |> st_cast('MULTIPOLYGON') |> st_set_crs(crs)
        )
}
```

2. helper function to rotate the geometry of a spatial dataframe

```
    rotate_feature <- function(feature,
                               angle = 0, ## rotation in degree
                               anchor = c(0, 0) ## top center point of grid
                               ){
      crs <- st_crs(feature)
      a <- -pi * angle/180 ## convert to radiant ccw
      ## create rotation matrix:
      rotmat <- matrix(c(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a)), 2, 2)
      ## rotate, recenter, restore CRS:
      st_geometry(feature) <- st_geometry(feature) * rotmat + anchor
      feature |> st_set_crs(crs)
    }
```

3. load libraries, create play data

```
    library(sf)
    library(dplyr)
    
    the_lake <- readRDS(file.choose()) ## spatial feature supplied by OP
    the_anchor <- c(5.08e5, 4.224e6) ## anchor strip grid here
```

4. generate desired spatial features

```
    the_strips <- 
      get_strips(crs = st_crs(the_lake)) |>
      rotate_feature(angle = 30, anchor = the_anchor)
    
    the_cropped_strips <- the_strips |>
      st_intersection(the_lake)
    
    ## casting polygons to multilinestrings to only
    ## obtain the corner points (not areas) on intersection:
    the_corners <- 
      st_intersection(
        st_cast(the_strips, 'MULTILINESTRING'),
        st_cast(the_lake, 'MULTILINESTRING')
      )
```

5. inspect

```
    library(ggplot2)
    
    anchor_point <- the_anchor |> st_point() |>
                                  st_sfc(crs = st_crs(the_lake))
    
    ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = the_lake) +
      geom_sf(data = the_strips, fill = NA) +
      geom_sf(data = the_cropped_strips, aes(fill = strip_id)) +
      geom_sf(data = the_corners) +
      geom_sf(data = anchor_point, pch = '+', size = 5) +
      geom_sf_label(data = anchor_point, nudge_y = 1e3, label = 'Anchor') +
      coord_sf(xlim = 1e5 * c(5, 5.2), ylim = 1e6 * c(4.21, 4.235))
```

[image: result map]

6. extract corners per polygon:

```
    the_corners |>
      rowwise() |>
      reframe(strip_id,
              coords = st_coordinates(geometry)
              )
```

```
    ## # A tibble: 50 x 2
    ##    strip_id coords[,1]     [,2]  [,3]
    ##    <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
    ##  1 strip_01    508864. 4223922.     1
    ##  2 strip_01    507927. 4223381.     1
    ##  3 strip_01    508230. 4222400.     1
    ##  4 strip_01    509328. 4223035.     1
    ##  5 strip_02    508230. 4222400.     1
    ##  6 strip_02    508791. 4221570.     1
```

Comment: I think this is terrific, and OP's challenge seems like establishing a search grid south of first point, to perhaps as much as a km in 50m strips, which I suppose might suggest Map(1:n, though I likely misunderstand. Were it, 50m strips on km, I'd crop out my km and work from there. Map(1:-n actually.

Comment: This looks really promising @I_O. One thing that stands out is the strings go onto the land. How do I keep the strips right on the edge of the shore on each side of the lake?

Comment: To keep the coast-to-coast trajectories only, you could swap the `intersection` arguments (keeping the lake as a polygon rather than a linestring) like so: `st_intersection(the_lake, the_parallels)`

Comment: ... and to obtain a matrix of the endpoints of each trajectory do: `st_intersection(the_lake, the_parallels) |> st_cast('MULTIPOINT') |>  st_coordinates()`, column L1 indicates the trajectory (two points per trajectory index, obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @I_O. Will try it out shortly. One last thing, How can I customize the strings to make them wider, for example, 1 mile, 1 km or 5 km? Where in the function I can make that change? Also, is there a way to identify the coordinates for each string?

Comment: To derive a poly from `parallels`,  `points_from_par_lines = st_cast(st_intersection(parallels[4:3], st_cast(bay, 'MULTILINESTRING')), 'POINT')`, `plot(st_polygon(list(st_coordinates(points_from_par_lines[c(1:2,4:3, 1)]))), col = 'red', add = TRUE)`, still working on grabbing the true line between the parallel slices.

Comment: That's the strip_width in `get_parallels(` for 5km, 10km etc. As Map(-n:n, parallels are from southmost to north, 1:7. Best I can say.

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to identify the coordinates that belong to each strip? The idea is to color each string based on a value that I have on my original dataset.

Comment: Color string or strip (rectangle), are your original values derived from transects, i.e. mean of samples along a sampling bearing?

Comment: Color the rectangle actually. For example, coordinates from the first rectangle will have a corresponding value on the same row, the second rectangle will have a different value on the same row as well and so on for each rectangle. I then will color code each rectangle based on that value. I will use scale_fill() for that purpose maybe. Let me know if is not clear enough.

Comment: Look at my comment `To derive a poly` from parallels, parallels number 1:7 here, south to north. parallels[4:3] was from line 4, the one through your original point, to 3, the next line south. Grab the intersection points, make a poly and fill. There's a lot going on here that will take some time to wrap my head around, should have paid more attention in trig class.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much you guys. Will wait for the final answer so I can put the check mark and end this long chain of comments.

Comment: This is it @I_O, This is what I was hoping for. To keep the strings from shore to shore only, flip the lake and strings as before?

Comment: Thank you both @I_O and Chris for your help. These functions would be even better if they were in a package. This is an unbelievable eye opener for me. Thanks again for educating me!!

Comment: Going through all your code @I_O , How did you come up with this format? `the_anchor <- c(5.08e5, 4.224e6) `

Comment: It's a vector of size two with the x and y coordinate (of given CRS). These two numeric values are used in `rotate_feature` to shift the rotated "carpet" of strips to extend from the anchor (instead of, initially, the origin of the coordinate system) southwards. I used a coordinate pair (instead of a fully fledged `sf` object) to keep the function reusable without {sf} ... you never know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with space filling polygons, here squares.

```
n100 = c(100,100)
bay_square_100 = st_make_grid(
bay,
cellsize = c(diff(st_bbox(bay)[c(1,3)]), diff(st_bbox(bay)[c(2,4)]))/n100,
offset = st_bbox(bay)[c('xmin', 'ymin')],
what = 'polygon',
square = TRUE
)
# get index of just the ones inside
bay_sq_100_cont = st_contains_properly(bay, bay_square_100)
contained_bay_sq = bay_square_100[unlist(bay_sq_100_cont)]
```

Index `contained_bay_sq` with the marvelously useful `cgwtools::seqle`, an rle for sequences, 1,2,3...i

```
end = cumsum(cgwtools::seqle(unlist(bay_sq_100_cont))$lengths)
start = end - cgwtools::seqle(unlist(bay_sq_100_cont))$lengths +1
```

This approach to `st_union` creates an object that is seemingly unworkable until you run across [knapply comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251641/how-to-combine-sfc-objects-from-r-package-sf), that reminds, or informs that `unlist` has a `recursive` argument.

```
unioned_rows = list()
for (i in 1:length(start)) {
unioned_rows[[i]] = st_union(c(bay_cont[start[i]:end[i]]))
}
unioned_row4 = st_sfc(unlist(unioned_rows, recursive = FALSE)) #many difficult objects created

plot(unioned_row4, col = c('red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange', 'pink') )
```

This can be done with hexagons and indexing along diagonals to create a faux angle, but I think @I_O 's approach is more elegantly flexible.

[image: Tomales Bay 100m colored strips]

Actually, the grid can be rotated as demonstrated [Stackoverflow - rotate grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282724/creating-a-regular-polygon-grid-over-a-spatial-extent-rotated-by-a-given-angle)

```
library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.12.0, GDAL 3.8.0, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
 bay = st_geometry(readRDS('~/Downloads/bay.RDS'))
 rot = function(a) matrix(c(cos(a), sin(a), -sin(a), cos(a)), 2, 2)
 tran = function(geo, ang, center) (geo - center) * rot(ang * pi / 180) + center
 center = st_centroid(st_union(bay))
 rotang = -30 # sign, -CounterClockWise +CW
 grd = st_make_grid(tran(bay, -rotang, center), cellsize = 100, crs = st_crs(bay))
 grd_rot = tran(grd, rotang, center)
 bay_rot_100_cont_idx = st_contains_properly(bay, grd_rot)
Error in st_geos_binop("contains_properly", x, y, sparse = sparse, prepared = TRUE,  : 
  st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE
 st_crs(grd_rot) = 26910
 bay_rot_100_cont_idx = st_contains_properly(bay, grd_rot)
 cont_bay_rot = grd_rot[unlist(bay_rot_100_cont_idx)]
 end_rot = cumsum(cgwtools::seqle(unlist(bay_rot_100_cont_idx))$lengths)
 start_rot = end_rot - cgwtools::seqle(unlist(bay_rot_100_cont_idx))$lengths + 1
 unioned_rows_rot = list()
 for (i in 1:length(start_rot)) {
 unioned_rows_rot[[i]] = st_union(c(cont_bay_rot[start_rot[i]:end_rot[i]]))
 }
 unioned_rot_sfc = st_sfc(unlist(unioned_rows_rot, recursive = FALSE)
plot(unioned_rot_sfc, col = c('green', 'white', 'red'))
```

[image: Tomales Bay rotated grid]